# Conversation ID's Transformation in Power Automate Email Processing - Underscore replaced in listing, Why?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I am working on an email processing workflow using Power Automate, and I've encountered a puzzling behavior related to Conversation ID's. Initially, when I receive an email in Power Automate, the Conversation ID contains an underscore (e.g., "ABCDEF_123456"). However, when I retrieve a list of Conversation ID's and examine them, the underscore is replaced with a different character format (e.g., "ABCDEF123456" ).

I'm trying to understand the reason behind this transformation. I assumed that the Conversation ID would remain consistent throughout the workflow, but it appears that Power Automate alters it when listing the ID's. Could someone shed some light on why this is happening?

Initially, conversationID was to be used to link emails that are within the same subject chain, but due to this irregularity with how the string is constructed I changed the flow to select the subject header and organise all emails based on date. This worked for a time before users started to change the headings and counts started to become more and more inaccurate. I also tried to log the conversationID within a powerapps table so that I could just perform a count function on it, but this was also too inefficient.

Any advice on how to work around this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.